# mainform.ui.qml is missing in new QtQuick project

Tags: qml, qt6

I'm pretty new in QT an have read/watched a lot of tutorials especially the QT documentation. Right now I'm stuck in creating new QTQuick projects.
I have installed QT 6.2 and using a windows (Win 10) computer.
Where ever I look I'm told, that QTCreator creates a file called mainform.ui.qml (when the concerning checkbox is checked) when setting up a new QtQuick project. In my case there isn't even a checkbox and after creating the project no mainform.ui.qml.
As far as I understood the tutorials there is no special adjustment to be done to generate this file.

Could anybody please give me a hint what to do to get this ui file generated automatically when creating a QTQuick application with QTCreator?

Thanks a lot in advance for taking care of my question.

Best regards from Bremen Germany

Comment: does your project compile and run? you probably have `main.qml`.

Comment: What version of Qt Creator are you using, and what tutorial are you following? They probably don't match. Files that end with `.ui` are UI forms used with Qt Creator's Designer tool for widgets projects. Files that end with `.ui.qml` are the same, but used for QML projects. I'm looking at Qt Creator 7.0 and I don't even see a way to use Designer with a QML project anymore. So maybe they've removed that functionality. You don't need it though. It should have generated a main.qml file, where you can write your UI code.

Comment: @folibis Thanks for your response. Yes the project compiles and is running without any problems and as this is a QTQuick project the main.qml is existing. There I did the coding.

Comment: @JarMan Thanks for your response. First of all I'm working with QTCreator 7.0.1. One of the manuals where I found the statement concerning the mainform.ui.qml is this one <https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtquickcontrols-chattutorial-example.html>. The designer for .ui.qml files is QT Design Studio (installed together with my QT package)  which is different from QT Designer. Maybe you're right and this has something to do which the version of QTCreator.

Comment: Sorry I have to update my last post. QT Design Studio is obviously a stand alone solution as a kind of strip down compared with QT Creator. You can create own projects with this designer. Concerning the *.ui.qml files there is another designer called QT Quick Designer which has been an integral part of QT Creator and according to a tutorial based on QT 5.5 it opens when you doubleclick the ui.qml file. And again, maybe it's correct, that generating a ui.qml file when creating a QT Quick application is no longer part of the QT Creator routine.